# Can surge.sh websites be indexed by google search?

Tags: surge.sh

Can websites created with the a *.surge.sh domain be indexed and found on Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Slack, domains of surge.sh cannot be indexed by any bot to prevent link farming. SAD :(

Comment: Can you post the link for reference?

Comment: I don't have any reference link but surge.sh auto-generate a hidden robots.txt file that cannot be located on the sources tab but it can be seen by going to: https://yoursite.surge.sh/robots.txt                                                                                             You will see:                                                                                                             
`User-agent: * Disallow: / `

Comment: And, surge.sh is not for deploying apps for large people. It is just for GitHub project demo purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand google SEO rules. There is a way to submit your website first. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

Then you need to SEO for your website.